# Can I get the Stack Exchange markdown toolbar on Reddit?

Tags: reddit, userscripts

I understand Reddit uses some kind of Markdown as well. Has anyone written a Chrome/FF userscript that imports the Stack Exchange toolbox (click here to Bold/Italic/Add Link) into Reddit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be of some use to you:

http://redditenhancementsuite.com/

Comment: Much more than I'd hoped - thanks.